# Background Service Limitations Android and voip app

Tags: android, service, voip, android-8.0-oreo

I am working on the voip app. I do all the logic regarding the signaling on background service. When user exists the app I am stoping the service. In this case, I am not connected to the server. When I am in this state, server is sending the push notification (FCM), I am starting the service and creating notification for incoming call or message. This is all good so far:)

I have read about the limitations for Oreo for backgrounding services and realize that now I need to start service in foreground while showing notification. Then I wanted to check how the Hangouts(google) does it, and of course they are running the service in the background when message is received. Am I missing something?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

#### Visible activity = foreground

> When user exists the app I am stoping the service

If this means that the service is running only when your app is visible to the user, then the process and the service is actually in the foreground and you shouldn't experience any problems with system killing your service:

> An app is considered to be in the foreground if any of the following is true:
>
> - It has a visible activity, whether the activity is started or paused.

#### FCM received = foreground

Also, receiving high-priority FCM messages will put your app on temporary whitelist for background processing, and you will have more than enough time to do your processing at that time, or you can always start a foreground service after FCM is received - like a service that handles the call and should display a notification while running:

> Under certain circumstances, a background app is placed on a temporary whitelist for several minutes. While an app is on the whitelist, it can launch services without limitation, and its background services are permitted to run. An app is placed on the whitelist when it handles a task that's visible to the user, such as:
>
> - Handling a high-priority Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) message.

---

Your app design - handling incoming calls by receiving priority FCM and then creating a foreground call service - seems reasonable.

Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) which is really clear on these subjects.

Comment: Yeah, I already planned to start it in the foreground but I am wondering how the Hangouts or Viber manage to do it without it. Especially if the document states:
_After the system has created the service, the app has five seconds to call the service's startForeground() method to show the new service's user-visible notification. If the app does not call startForeground() within the time limit, the system stops the service and declares the app to be ANR._ Of course I suppose they have build target set to 26:)

Comment: Do you mean, these apps do not show a foreground notification while the call is active? Also, does closing the app "kill" the call or not? (I don't use neither viber nor hangouts)

Comment: I am talking about the messages and notification for the incoming call (not new stuff).
Scenario for hangout for example:
When hangouts are not running and you receive message. Notification is shown. When you go to developer options -> running services you see that Hangouts have service running (not in foreground mode)...